# C-style wrapper to C++ member function, ordinary function pointer to member function

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member, template-argument-deduction

So I sort of tried to accomplish [“the impossible”](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#memfnptr-vs-fnptr) at least in C++20 and with the constraint that the class for which I am extracting a member function pointer can be evaluated as a `constexpr`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct AddFunctor
{
    double val;
    double operator()(double x) const { return val + x; }
};

struct SubFunctor
{
    double val;
    double operator()(double x) const { return val - x; }
};

typedef double(*DblFn)(double);  // C-style type of above operator()

// the below is doable only in C++20 which is more liberal about NTTP-s
template<typename FunctorType, FunctorType functor>
double functorWrapper(double x) { return functor(x); }

// below wrapper doesn't work, see below
template<typename FunctorType>
DblFn makeWrapper(FunctorType fr) { return &(functorWrapper<FunctorType, fr>); }

int main()
{
    DblFn fp;
    
    // if constexpr below is changed to const, one gets:
    // error: assigning to 'DblFn' (aka 'double (*)(double)') from incompatible type '<overloaded function type>'
    constexpr AddFunctor af{2};
    constexpr SubFunctor sf{3};

    // fp = &(af.operator());  // error: cannot create a non-constant pointer to member function

    fp = &(functorWrapper<AddFunctor, af>);
    std::cout << fp(6.283) << std::endl;

    fp = &(functorWrapper<SubFunctor, sf>);
    std::cout << fp(6.283) << std::endl;

// if the below "if 0" block is uncommented, one gets:
/*
<src>:21:46: error: address of overloaded function 'functorWrapper' does not match required type 'double (double)'
DblFn makeWrapper(FunctorType fr) { return &(functorWrapper<FunctorType, fr>); }
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<src>:40:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'makeWrapper<AddFunctor>' requested here
    fp = makeWrapper(af);
        ^
<src>:18:8: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'functor'
double functorWrapper(double x) { return functor(x); }
    ^
1 error generated.
*/
#if 0
    fp = makeWrapper(af);
    std::cout << fp(2.718) << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

As I am not C++-savvy enough, I ask this question: is it possible to write a `makeWrapper` function as I have tried to do without manually specifying the FunctorType and find it out using template argument type deduction, and if yes how?

PS: My library is implemented in C++ for it's expressive power but the interface is basically C for FFI flexibility with `ifdef __cplusplus` function goodies available. Hence I'm specifically looking for solutions for my C++ clients to convert to C-style pointers to maintain a common ABI.

Comment: You take a function with two parameters and wrap a function with one parameter around it, passing a constant as the other parameter. Nothing remotely impossible here.

Comment: A regular function parameter is never a `constexpr` so `makewrapper(af)` cannot possibly work. `makewrapper<af>()` could work.

Comment: Any suggestions for wordings of `makeWrapper<af>()`?

Comment: The "impossible" part was for the C-style pointer bit. Of course in C++ much more is possible.

Comment: I guess it makes sense that only something that can be constexpr-ed at compile time can be taken for construction of templated code. So it is possible that a pointer to a bound member function of an object of externally varying state will still be impossible to even wrap like this without the usage of globals. But I wanted to ask because others will certainly have more experience than me.

Comment: Simple, `template<auto Functor> DblFn makeWrapper() { return &(functorWrapper<decltype(Functor), Functor>); }`

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), this is rather a simple case of wrapping the `class::operator()` into a lambda function.

```
#include <functional>

using DblFn = std::function<double(double)>;

template<typename FunctorType>
constexpr auto makeWrapper(FunctorType functor)
{
   // Define the lambda directly as a function pointer
   return [=](double x) { return functor(x); };
}
```

Now you can

```
AddFunctor af{ 2 };
const SubFunctor sf{ 3 };
constexpr SubFunctor xf{ -8 };

DblFn fp = makeWrapper(af);
std::cout << fp(6.283) << std::endl;   // prints: 8.283

fp = makeWrapper(sf);
std::cout << fp(6.283) << std::endl;   // prints: -3.283


fp = makeWrapper(xf);
std::cout << fp(6.283) << std::endl;   // prints: -14.283
```

[Live demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xbYGqqad9)

The c-style function pointers require the type of the member functions to be accurate (i.e. `const`, non `const`, `noexcept` etc.); hence the issue! On the other hand `std::function` helps you with its [type erasure power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450159/what-type-erasure-techniques-are-there-and-how-do-they-work) to capture, the wrapper [(stateful) lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052161/what-is-the-difference-between-a-stateful-and-a-stateless-lambda-expression) and achieve the goal.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I guess I should have been more explicit that I was specifically looking for an option to convert a member pointer to a C-style pointer and that having read https://stackoverflow.com/a/48355758/ I had tried lambdas, binds etc and they are not convertible to C-style.